# Exception message not printing when I give a string character

Tags: python, exception

`I'm trying to get this exception to trigger so I can see if python can handle when I input a string instead of an int.

I've tried changing the ValueError statement to a different type of exception such as TypeError instead of Value Error. I've also checked for syntax issues.

```py
try:
    u_list.append(userInput)
    if userInput % 2 == 0:
        list_sum += userInput
except ValueError: #this is supposed to be thrown when I put
    # a string character instead of an int. Why is this 
    #not being invoked
    #when I put a str character in?!?!
    print("da fuq!?!. That ain't no int!")
```

I'm trying to get the program to print my last line shown when I input a string character, such as a (k) or something, instead it's throwing an error message.

Here's the full code that someone asked for:

```
    u_list = []
    list_sum = 0
    for i in range(10):
        userInput = int(input("Gimme a number: "))
        try:
                u_list.append(userInput)
                if userInput % 2 == 0:
                    list_sum += userInput
        except ValueError: #this is supposed to be thrown when I put
                            # a string character instead of an int. Why is this not being invoked
                            #when I put a str character in?!?!
                print("da fuq!?!. That ain't no int!")

    print("u_list: {}".format(u_list))
    print("The sum of tha even numbers in u_list is: {}.".format(list_sum))
```

Comment: Which line do you think will throw `ValueError` here?

Comment: and Error message is..? I think it will throw `TypeError` rather than `ValueError` Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605512/python-difference-between-valueerror-and-exception

Comment: Add the full code. What is `u_list`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: difference between ValueError and Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605512/python-difference-between-valueerror-and-exception)

Comment: @ParthS007 ive added the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError` will be thrown when failing to convert a string to an int. `input()` (or `raw_input()` in Python 2) will always return a string, even if that string contains digits, and trying to treat it like an integer will not implicitly convert it for you. Try something like this:

```
try:
    userInput = int(userInput)
except ValueError:
    ...
else:
    # Runs if there's no ValueError
    u_list.append(userInput)
    ...
```

Comment: So did yours, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `userInput` in the try-except block and check it for `ValueError`. If its an integer then append it to the list.

Here's the Code:

```py
u_list = []
list_sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    try:
        userInput = int(input("Gimme a number: "))
    except ValueError:
            print("da fuq!?!. That ain't no int!")

    u_list.append(userInput)
    if userInput % 2 == 0:
        list_sum += userInput

print("u_list: {}".format(u_list))
print("The sum of tha even numbers in u_list is: {}.".format(list_sum))
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to help @Bileboar, Please mark the answers as accepted or upvote it if they helped you :)